# "to make somebody very interested and want to know more about something"

Tags: prepositions

This is a definition of 'intrigue' in [the Oxford Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/intrigue_1?q=intrigue).

> [transitive] to make somebody very interested and want to know more
> about something

Considering that adjective 'interested' is usually followed by preposition 'in', I think it is better to rewrite the definition as follows.

*to make somebody very interested **in** and want to know more about something*

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Interested" may be followed by a prepositional phrase "in..." but it's not mandatory. The thing that interests you may be implied by context.

> There's a job advertised as a gardener. What do you think?
>
> Yes, I'm interested, and I might apply for it, if the pay is enough.

There is no need to treat this as a phrasal verb "interested in". There is no need to insert "in" in the quoted definition.

Comment: Thank you very much.